# Create an online forum

Tags: database, frontend, backend, forum

so I've been thinking about expanding my coding language by creating an online forum. I think I have a basic idea what you need in order to code one, but I wonder if there's a more specific documentation about it. I would really appreciate, if you could share a .pdf file with me or some free online course. I generally don't like spending money on something I can do for free, so just don't share paid courses. If there's isn't one, I have a question.

To make a proper online forum you need have a database to store all the topics, frontend and a backend that will make these two things cooperate. What is the best language for the backend? I have no idea which one should I use for this project. Is there anything else you need in order to create a forum? I'm not a beginner coder, but I haven't ever tried to make something like this.

Answer (score 1):

## My problem with the question

I recognize that you want a guide for how to build a data-base driven website (that's the term you would want to google for more specific help, btw), but your question actually makes it so I can't give anything more specific. If you don't have a back-end framework picked, there's literally no way for me to give a specific guide to your problem. With that all said, I want to do my best to help you, by answering your question!

"What is the best language for the backend?" This question has no answer, or at least, no answer that could possibly be demonstrably correct. There are dozens of back-end frameworks and structures because there's so many different philosophies, trade-offs, coding styles, and preferences to application design that nothing would meet everyones needs, but something will meet *your* needs.

Here's where I have three recommendations for back-end structures that are "batteries included." That is to say, you don't need to pickout other elements of your tech-stack to start getting something deployed and working. These are organized as "Language:Framework to Deploy Language + reason I mention it"

## Where you could start

1. Python:Django.

---

This one is near and dear to my heart, I personally love it for small scale websites that don't need all the bells and whistles for the scale I am looking at, but it does have some bits of "jank" because Python was not really meant for the task it is handling. It doesn't have any errors, just some weird design patterns.

2. VB/C#: .NET (I recommend .NET core in particular).

---

This is a very common one for production, but can be a bit more bloated for solo development, imo. I work with it professionally for my job and I don't like it because of how limited you get with the more opinionated designs .NET requires, but it has everything I need, and the studio editor (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) is pretty nice.

3. Ruby:RubyOnRails.

---

I have used it only a very small amount and couldn't give you particular pros and cons other than this: it's very popular -> many tutorials, developers to hire, stackoverflow questions, etc. It is definitely able to handle what ever database driven website you have in mind.

## As a final note

, this is not a full list, nor should it be *all* you look at if you find all of these frameworks to be annoying or unintuitive in someway (or all the progamming languages listed are completely out of your wheelhouse). That's really where I would start, because that's how I started in web-dev. I have a massive amount of Python experience so I looked up how to build a website using Python for the back-end + deployment and Django + Flask came-up. I learned them, made serveral sites, and it was very intuitive to me. If I started with Node.JS (when I didn't know JS that well) I would have probably given up.